# Efficient way to compute number of hits to a server within the last minute, in real time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Say you have a server that constantly gets HTTP requests. Your boss needs some stats, and asks you to compute the number of hits within the last minute at any given time.

What algorithm and data-structure would you use to achieve this?

Comment: Does the boss expect the stats to change all over the time or he will just be happy with 1-4 values per minute?

Comment: @MichałGórny, I don't understand your question. Boss needs the EXACT amount of hits at any given time -- no approximations.

Comment: As far as I understand you, the server gets a lot of requests in that minute. How can you define *exact* number of hits when new hits happen already when you are still in progress of displaying the previous ones? It's always approximate; it's just what error boundary you accept. You can try to do a thing you'd call 'exact' but if you get a lot of hits, you will just waste your CPU power. Wouldn't your boss be satisfied by a value which gets updated every, say, 2 seconds? That's much simpler to accomplish, and definitely faster.

Comment: I don't see why it has to be approximate, i.e., at this exact second count all the hits within the last minute. Any future hits are no longer in this exact second but in the future. Of course approximation makes it simpler, but the question specifically asks for exact results to make it more challenging. This is just a brain teaser, not really necessary for most practical purposes.

Answer (score 8):

Use a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Whenever you have to keep some current statistics with a built-in obsolescence, a ring buffer is a good candidate. In your case, you can easily keep count of the requests in the last minute by inserting new packets at the front of the circular buffer and keeping a one-minute-before-now pointer in the buffer, or performing a binary search on request time.

Answer (score 1):

An [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), of which an append-only file is the on-disk counterpart. Just append each hit to the array as it comes in, so it's sorted by time. Appending takes amortized constant time. You can do a binary search (or interpolation search) to find the point where the last minute starts, then sum up to the end in O(lg *n*) (or (O(lg lg *n*)) time.

Alternatively, do a linear scan from the end instead of binary search, which will be faster if the file grows very large and you only ever need the last minute. If the expected number of hits in the last minute is independent of time, this takes only constant time (but reading a file on a spinning disk backwards can be slow).

If you don't have the space to store all the old data, then using a deque is a better idea. Good implementations of deques are available in the standard libraries of, e.g., C++ and Python.

Comment: On a busy web server, you need a way to "forget" old queries, i.e. remove them from the data structure, or you will exhaust the memory soon. A dynamic array is pretty bad at deleting elements from the front.

Comment: @thiton: true. Updated my answer by suggesting a deque instead. I also like your idea of using a ring buffer, though, so +1 for that.