# How can I count the number of requests in the last second, minute and hour?

Tags: algorithm, web-services, data-structures

I have a web server which supports only one very simple API- count the number of requests received in the last hour, minute and second.
This server is very popular in the world and received thousands of requests per second.

Aim it to find how to return accurately these 3 values to every request?

Requests are coming all the time, so the window of one hour, one minute and one second is different per request.
How to manage a different window per request so that the counts are correct per request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to compute number of hits to a server within the last minute, in real time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701008/efficient-way-to-compute-number-of-hits-to-a-server-within-the-last-minute-in-r)

Answer (score 35):

**If 100% accuracy is required:**

Have a linked-list of all requests and 3 counts - for the last hour, the last minute and the last second.

You will have 2 pointers into the linked-list - for a minute ago and for a second ago.

An hour ago will be at the end of the list. Whenever the time of the last request is more than an hour before the current time, remove it from the list and decrement the hour count.

The minute and second pointers will point to the first request that occurred after a minute and a second ago respectively. Whenever the time of the request is more than a minute / second before the current time, shift up the pointer and decrement the minute / second count.

When a new request comes in, add it to all 3 counts and add it to the front of the linked-list.

Requests for the counts would simply involve returning the counts.

All of the above operations are amortised constant time.

**If less than 100% accuracy is acceptable:**

The space-complexity for the above could be a bit much, depending on how many requests per second you would typically get; you can reduce this by sacrificing slightly on accuracy as follows:

Have a linked-list as above, but only for the last second. Also have the 3 counts.

Then have a circular array of 60 elements indicating the counts of each of the last 60 seconds. Whenever a second passes, subtract the last (oldest) element of the array from the minute count and add the last second count to the array.

Have a similar circular array for the last 60 minutes.

*Loss of accuracy:* The minute count can be off by all the requests in a second and the hour count can be off by all the requests in a minute.

Obviously this won't really make sense if you only have one request per second or less. In this case you can keep the last minute in the linked-list and just have a circular array for the last 60 minutes.

There are also other variations on this - the accuracy to space used ratio can be adjusted as required.

**A timer to remove old elements:**

If you remove old elements only when new elements come in, it will be amortised constant time (some operations might take longer, but it will average out to constant time).

If you want true constant time, you can additionally have a timer running which removes old elements, and each invocation of this (and of course insertions and checking the counts) will only take constant time, since you're removing at most a number of elements inserted in the constant time since the last timer tick.

Comment: In the "100% accuracy" method, how is the array shift and decrement operation constant time? Linear scan through a list to remove all the old requests would be O(n), e.g. imagine a worst case of 1000 requests in 0.1 seconds, 1 second later you need to scan and remove 1000 entries, now image a million requests, you would need to scan and remove 1 million entries - the work required is growing as a function of the number of requests that need to be removed, it is not constant time. Even if the number of expired requests in the list is some constant fraction of n, it is still O(n).

Comment: @bain the benefit of the "linked list" data structure is that you do not need to pass over all the elements to add/remove like you would with a simple array and push/shift. To remove an element you can simply remove or rearrange the "links".

Comment: @patmood Adding or removing nodes in a linked list is O(1), but traversal of a linked list is O(n). The "pointer shift and counter decrement" described here requires traversing the linked list until we find the first node storing a request that occurred less than one hour (or minute, or second) from the current time. In the worst-case, this requires traversing all _n_ nodes in the list and calling the decrement operator _n_ times.

Comment: bain - no need to traverse... create a variable named sum and add new element and subtract old element.. thats why he/she meant O(1)

Comment: @bain If you remove old elements only when new elements come in, it will be amortised constant time (some operations might take longer, but it will average out to constant time). However, you can additionally have a timer running which removes old elements, and each invocation of this (and of course insertions and checking the counts) will only take constant time, since you're removing at most a number of elements inserted in the constant time since the last timer tick (admittedly that falls apart a bit when the work required takes longer than the timer interval).

Comment: I agree for the constant timer that ticks and remove items, it will prevent mass removing for large slices of time where there are no requests

Comment: How does the second method lead to less than 100 % accuracy ? I mean how does the total count of a unit get off by the last subunit ? We are counting the last second count as well only then are we summing the minute count, then why could the minute count be off by the last second ??

Comment: @RohitashwaNigam You do the update described in my answer when a second passes. If you check the count at this exact point, it will be accurate. But if you check the count halfway through a second, the second which was 60 seconds ago will be a problem - you will not know how many requests happened in the earlier half (which should be excluded) and the later half (which should be included) of that second. All of them might have happened in the first half, or the second half, or an equal amount of times in both halves. Of course you can just show the accurate count, but then there's a delay.

Answer (score 17):

To do this for time window of T seconds, have a queue data structure where you queue the timestamps of individual requests as they arrive. When you want to read the number of requests arrived during the most recent window of T seconds, first drop from the "old" end of the queue those timestamps that are older than T seconds, then read the size of the queue. You should also drop elements whenever you add a new request to the queue to keep its size bounded (assuming bounded rate for incoming requests).

This solution works up to arbitrary precision, e.g. millisecond accuracy. If you are content with returning approximate answers, you can e.g. for time window of T = 3600 (an hour), consolidate requests coming within same second into a single queue element, making queue size bounded by 3600. I think that would be more than fine, but theoretically loses accuracy. For T = 1, you can do consolidation on millisecond level if you want.

In pseudocode:

```
queue Q

proc requestReceived()
  Q.insertAtFront(now())
  collectGarbage()

proc collectGarbage()
  limit = now() - T
  while (! Q.empty() && Q.lastElement() < limit)
    Q.popLast()

proc count()
  collectGarbage()
  return Q.size()
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not just use a circular array?
We have 3600 elements in that array.

```
index = 0;
Array[index % 3600] = count_in_one_second. 
++index;
```

if you want last second, return the last element of this array. 
if you want last minute, return the sum of last 60 elements.
if you want last hour, return the sum of the whole array (3600 elements).

Isn't his a simple and effective solution?

Thanks

Deryk

Comment: I like it. How about using current time (e.g. System.currentTimeMillis()) instead of index?

Comment: It is simple, but we also need a separate counter for each second. After every second, it should update the value in Array element for that second ?

Comment: I like this idea and it works nicely while you have continuous requests coming in every second, but what will happen when you don't have requests for some of the entries in the array? If we reduce the problem of only providing counters for last second and last minute then suppose you have n requests for second 4, but none for second 3. In this case you should clean old data for second 3, and generally clean back until you either reach second 0 or an entry of the same minute. Cleaning data in front should be done only for stale data older than current minute - 1.

Comment: If the stale data is a concern, we can have an array with size of 7200. clean the next 3600 elements once you reach index of 3600th and 7200th element.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is like this:

1. Use **a circular array of length 3600** (60 * 60 seconds in an hour) to hold the data for each second in last hour.

To record the data for a new second, drop the last second's data in the circular array by moving the circular array's head pointer.

2. In each element of the circular array, instead of holding the number of requests in a particular second, we record **the cumulative sum** for the number of requests we see previously, and the number of requests for a period can be calculated by `requests_sum.get(current_second) - requests_sum.get(current_second - number_of_seconds_in_this_period)`

All of the operations like `increment()`, `getCountForLastMinute()`, `getCountForLastHour()` can be done in `O(1)` time.

=========================================================================

Here is an example for how this works.

If we have request count in recent 3 seconds like this:

```
1st second: 2 requests
2nd second: 4 requests
3rd second: 3 requests
```

The circular array will look like this:
`sum = [2, 6, 9]`
where 6 = 4 + 2 and 9 = 2 + 4 + 3

In this case:

1. if you want to get the last second's request count (the 3rd second's request count), simply calculating `sum[2] - sum[1] = 9 - 6 = 3`
2. if you want to get the last two seconds' request count (the 3rd second's request count and the 2nd second's request count), simply calculating `sum[2] - sum[0] = 9 - 2 = 7`

Comment: how will handles scenario in case there are no request ins some seconds?We might read old data incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of size 60x60 for each second in the hour and use it as circular buffer. Each entry contains number of requests for a given second. When you move to next second, clear it and start counting. When you are at then end of array, you start from 0 again, so effectively clearing all counts prior to 1 hour.

1. For Hour: return sum of all elements
2. For Minute: return sum of last 60 entries (from currentIndex)
3. For Second: return count on the currentIndex

So all three have O(1) space and time complexity. Only drawback is, it ignores milliseconds, but you can apply same notion to include milliseconds as well.

Comment: cant we have sliding widow type of solution instead of fixed intervals?

Answer (score 1):

[Following](https://jsfiddle.net/nishchal/g69b4w9e/6/) code is in JS. It will return you the count in O(1). I wrote this program for an interview where time was pre defined to be 5 minutes. But you can modify this code for seconds, minutes, and so on. Let me know how it goes.

1. Create an Object that will have milliseconds as key and counter as value
2. Add a property called totalCount and predefine it to be 0
3. With each log of hits increment counter defined in step 1 and the totalCount
4. Add a method called clean_hits, call this method every millisecond
5. In clean_hits method remove each entry (outside our time range) from the object that we created and subtract that count from totalCount before you delete the entry

   `this.hitStore = { "totalCount" : 0};`

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this problem in Go, and I don't think I saw this approach yet, but it may also be very specific to my use case.

Since it is connecting to a 3rd party API and needs to limit its own requests, I simply kept a counter for the last second and a counter for the last 2 minutes (the two counters I needed)

```
var callsSinceLastSecond, callsSinceLast2Minutes uint64
```

Then I'd launch my requests in separate go routines when the calls counters were below my allowable limit

```
for callsSinceLastSecond > 20 || callsSinceLast2Minutes > 100 {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

And at the end of each go routine I would atomically decrement the counter.

```
go func() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    atomic.AddUint64(&callsSinceLastSecond, ^uint64(0))
}()

go func() {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Minute)
    atomic.AddUint64(&callsSinceLast2Minutes, ^uint64(0))
}()
```

And that seems to work so far without any issue with some pretty heavy testing so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic Java solution that can keep track of the number of events for the last minute.

The reason I used `ConcurrentSkipListSet` is because it guarantees O(log N) average time complexity for search, insert and remove operations. You can easily change the code below to make the duration (1 minute by default) configurable.

As suggested in the answers above, it is a good idea to clean up stale entries periodically, using a scheduler for example.

```java
@Scope(value = "prototype")
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TemporalCounter {

    @Builder
    private static class CumulativeCount implements Comparable<CumulativeCount> {

        private final Instant timestamp;
        private final int cumulatedValue;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(CumulativeCount o) {
            return timestamp.compareTo(o.timestamp);
        }
    }

    private final CurrentDateTimeProvider currentDateTimeProvider;
    private final ConcurrentSkipListSet<CumulativeCount> metrics = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Instant now = currentDateTimeProvider.getNow().toInstant();
        metrics.add(new CumulativeCount(now, 0));
    }

    public void increment() {
        Instant now = currentDateTimeProvider.getNow().toInstant();
        int previousCount = metrics.isEmpty() ? 0 : metrics.last().cumulatedValue;
        metrics.add(new CumulativeCount(now, previousCount + 1));
    }

    public int getLastCount() {
        if (!metrics.isEmpty()) {
            cleanup();

            CumulativeCount previousCount = metrics.first();
            CumulativeCount mostRecentCount = metrics.last();
            if (previousCount != null && mostRecentCount != null) {
                return mostRecentCount.cumulatedValue - previousCount.cumulatedValue;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        Instant upperBoundInstant = currentDateTimeProvider.getNow().toInstant().minus(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
        CumulativeCount c = metrics.lower(CumulativeCount.builder().timestamp(upperBoundInstant).build());
        if (c != null) {
            metrics.removeIf(o -> o.timestamp.isBefore(c.timestamp));
            if (metrics.isEmpty()) {
                init();
            }
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        metrics.clear();
        init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution :

1. Maintain a hash of 3600 ,which contains a count,timestamp as fields.
2. For each request for:

   - get idx(index in arry for current element) by timestamp%3600.
   - if hash[idx].count=0, then hash[idx].count=1 and
     hash[idx].timestamp=inputTimeStamp
   - if hash[idx].count>0 ,then

   Case(1) : if i/p timestamp==hash[idx].timestamp,hash[count]++;

   Case(2) : if i/p timestamp>hash[idx].timestamp,then hash[idx].count=1 and
   hash[idx].timestamp=inputTimeStamp

   Case(3): : if i/p timestamp<hash[idx].count // old request, can be ignored.

Now for any query for last second,minute,hour:
Find idx as above, and as long as the timestamp matches with in given second/range/minute,keep on iterating back from from idx in circular manner.

Comment: What does "i/p" mean in this context? Should the condition for case 3 be "timestamp<hash[idx].timestamp"?

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple list of timestamps? Each time you're making a request you append the current timestamp to the list. And each time you want to check if you're under the rate limit, you first remove timestamps older than 1 hour to prevent stack overflow (hehe) then you count the number of timestamps in the last second, minute, whatever.

It could be done easily in Python:

```
import time

requestsTimestamps = []

def add_request():
    requestsTimestamps.append(time.time())

def requestsCount(delayInSeconds):
    requestsTimestamps = [t for t in requestsTimestamps if t >= time.time() - 3600]
    return len([t for t in requestsTimestamps if t >= time.time() - delayInSeconds])
```

I guess this can be optimized but you see the idea.