# meteor rest api using iron-router, limit rest api request

Tags: api, meteor, iron-router

i created services or REST APIs using meteor and iron-router.
i found a user do request almost `10.000` requests per minute. 
i think that i can limit request per minute like instagram or facebook REST APIs.

this is my rest api code using `iron-router`

```
Router.route('/api/:col_name/getall', {
    where: 'server'
})
    .get(function () {
        var request = this.request.query;
        var resultTokenCheck = Meteor.call("CheckToken", request.userid, request.token);
        if (resultTokenCheck.is_success) {
            if (request.data && request.by) {
                var result = Meteor.call('InsecureFindBy', this.params.col_name, request.data, request.by);
                this.response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
            else{
                var result = Meteor.call('InsecureFind', this.params.col_name);

                this.response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        }
        else {
            this.response.end(JSON.stringify(resultTokenCheck));
        }
    })
    .post(function () {
        this.response.end(JSON.stringify({
            message: Helpers.Api.DenyPost,
            is_success: false
        }));
    });
```

but how to limit meteor api request? for example user with role free only can 100 per minutes, advance user can request 10000 perminutes.
thanks

Comment: I assume you have the roles set in your user collection. Why don't you check for the roles into the `.get` and `.post` functions? Afaik, you could just check for the status, increment a count value for the previous requests amount per minute, and return your response accordingly.

Comment: i still not doing that because i still dont know the best practice, is that good if i create a log for every request? how to count this minute how much request happening?

Comment: I don't know either if it is a good idea to add db requests within an API method definition. Concerning the how to count it, I wouldn't want to log every request. Have a look at this topic for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17566127/3793161